# Making a vertical navigation between banner and footer

Tags: html

I am running into a few issues on an assignment I am working on.

Would really appreciate some help if it's something small I am missing or if I am completely off track with my code.

The issues I am having are, I can't seem to make my navbar stretch between my banner and footer sections. I also can't seem to get my content div and the table of images within it to align to the left of the navbar.

The code I have so far is: https://pastebin.com/cFVMRCaM

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Bazaar Ceramics</title>

<style>

body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.mainwrapper {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
}

.pagebanner {
    height: 250px;
    margin: 0;
}

.pagebanner img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.main {
    margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
    background-color: brown;
    height: 100%;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 
}

.navbar li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}



.headers {
    width: 80%;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.header {
    background-color: #000;
    text-align: center;
}

.header h1 {
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
}

.subheading {
    background-color: #f8d631;
    text-align: center;
}

.subheading h2 {
    background-color: #f8d631;
    margin: 0;
}

.content {
    position: relative;
    align: left;

}

.table {

    padding-left:500px
    border: 20px;
    }
.footer {
    background-color: darkgreen;
    height:20px;
    margin-bottom: inherit;

}   
</style>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="mainwrapper">
        <div class="pagebanner">
          <img src="../images/banner.jpg"="PageBanner">
        </div><!--PageBanner-->
    <div class="main">
        <div class="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Information</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--Navbar-->

    <div class="headers">
    <div class="header">
            <h1>The Club Site</h1>
    </div><!--Main page heading section-->

    <div class="subheading">
            <h2>Members Prices</h2>
    </div><!--Sub heading section-->
    </div>

    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="table">   
            <table>
            <th>Discount Prices</th>
            <tr><td><img src="../images/smaller/bcpot002_smaller.jpg"</td>
                 <td><img src="../images/smaller/bcpot002_smaller.jpg"</td>
                 <td><img 
               src="../images/smaller/bcpot010_smaller.jpg"</td></tr>
                <tr><td><img src="HTML Pract 
               A/images/smaller/bcpot002_smaller.jpg"</td><td><img src="HTML 
               Pract A/images/smaller/bcpot006_smaller.jpg"</td><td><img 
               src="HTML Pract A/images/smaller/bcpot013_smaller.jpg"</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
        </div><!--Table Section-->  

      </div><!--Content section-->

    <div class="footer">
      <footer>wsrgferg</footer>
    </div><!--Footer section-->
    </div><!--Endwrapper-->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So you want the navbar to be a vertical one on the left side? Make it `position:fixed;` with a top and bottom of 0, and then make the banner, headers, content, and footer have a `margin-left:20%;`

Comment: Tried that. Making the navbar position fixed makes it scroll with the page. I need it to be static and extend from the bottom of the banner to the top of the footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, then the below should be what you wanted. Using absolute positioning and moving all of the content except the banner and footer into the .main div. Position the .main div relatively and the navbar absolutely. Give the other inner content sections a margin-left of 20%;

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Bazaar Ceramics</title>

<style>

body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.mainwrapper {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
}

.pagebanner {
    height: 250px;
    margin: 0;
}

.pagebanner img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.main {
    margin: 0;
    position:relative;
}

.navbar {
    background-color: brown;
    width: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    
}

.navbar li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}



.headers {
    width: 80%;
    margin-left:20%;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.header {
    background-color: #000;
    text-align: center;
}

.header h1 {
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
}

.subheading {
    background-color: #f8d631;
    text-align: center;
}

.subheading h2 {
    background-color: #f8d631;
    margin: 0;
}

.content {
    position: relative;
    margin-left:20%;

}

.table {

    padding-left:500px
    border: 20px;
    }
.footer {
    background-color: darkgreen;
    height:20px;
    margin-bottom: inherit;

}   
</style>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="mainwrapper">
        <div class="pagebanner">
          <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/500/300" id="PageBanner">
        </div><!--PageBanner-->
    <div class="main">
        <div class="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Information</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--Navbar-->

    <div class="headers">
    <div class="header">
            <h1>The Club Site</h1>
    </div><!--Main page heading section-->

    <div class="subheading">
            <h2>Members Prices</h2>
    </div><!--Sub heading section-->
    </div>

    
    <div class="content">
      <div class="table">   
            <table>
            <th>Discount Prices</th>
            <tr><td><img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/200/100"></td>
                 <td><img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/200/100"></td>
                 <td><img 
               src="http://www.fillmurray.com/200/100"></td></tr>
                <tr><td><img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/200/100"></td><td><img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/200/100"></td><td><img 
               src="http://www.fillmurray.com/200/100"></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
        </div><!--Table Section-->  

      </div><!--Content section-->
</div>
    <div class="footer">
      <footer>wsrgferg</footer>
    </div><!--Footer section-->
    </div><!--Endwrapper-->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are awesome. Thank you so much for this. I have typed out this code 20 times easily. Again, thank you.

Comment: Happy to help, for future occurrences just remember, when positioning something absolutely, it's positioned according to its parent's position...but divs don't have an automatic position, so you have to give it a position of relative even if it's already behaving like a relatively positioned element :)